# ASP.Net MVC:File url masking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I have asp.net MVC application that has some anchor elements. The anchor elements lead to static files such as

`https://server/website/folder/subFolder/anotherSubFolder/File.pdf`

The files are all hosted in the web application domain in IIS.
When the link is clicked, this file is opened in a new browser window. Is it possible to mask this URL in the browser? The file should open, but the URL should NOT point to the exact path of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,
In any `Controller` you want, make an `Action` by the name `File`. The body of the action is:

```
public ActionResult File(string fileName)
{
    var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/" + fileName);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(path,
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read
    );
    var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    return fsResult;
}
```

and the anchor is:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("File", "Home", new { filename = "file.pdf" })" target="_blank">Open File</a>
```

In this way the url becomes something like this:

`http://localhost:4268/Home/File?filename=file.pdf`

Comment: Abbas, thanks for the response. I'll try this out and let you know how it turns out.